# PHP won't insert in mysql in XAMPP in linux

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried many things. This is the simplest form I can try to see if all is working.

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "xxxx";
$mysql_username="xxxx";
$mysql_password="xxxxx";
$mysql_database="test2";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} echo "Connected successfully";


$sql = "INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`,`firstname`) VALUES ('3','james')";

echo "-----------";
echo "-----------";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test_table`";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The table already contains 2 dummy inputs that I can insert from phpmyadmin.

When I try the above I get:

> Connected successfully----------------------id: 1 - Name: john
>   id: 2 - Name: ghost

I can't see where I am going wrong. 
Could it be that I need some kind of permissions change for this in linux?
That would be odd, I don't remember doing this before.

Comment: What do you expect to see? do you realise you don't actually run the `INSERT`. Just assign it to your `$sql` variable.

Comment: as @davidsheldon said you are not running the "INSERT" query, you are simply overwriting the `$sql` variable and after that you are running the query only for "SELECT". Run `$conn->query($sql);` after the `$sql = "INSERT ..... ";`

Comment: Hi guys.. You are absolutely correct. I can't believe how I didn't see that!